# Get all data from a list WCF

Tags: c#, loops, wcf, arraylist

I pass a string to my WCF service like this

```
http://localhost:49854/Service1.svc/rest/getData/station_number=("31098","31508","31273")
```

My IService:

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "*" ,ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "getData/station_number=({number})")]
    IEnumerable<Data> getData(string number);
```

Then that string will be cut into smaller piece by `,` then add to a list, after that i will loop though that list then get data that match list member like this:

```
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public IEnumerable<Data> getData(string number)
    {
        string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Bokeh_data"].ConnectionString;
        List<string> new_list = new List<string>();
        new_list = number.Split(',').ToList();
        List<Data> data_cont = new List<Data>();
        Data dt = new Data();
        for (var i = 0; i< new_list.Count; i++)
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cs))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetData_byvalue", conn);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@number", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = new_list[i];
                conn.Open();
                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while(reader.Read())
                {
                    dt.bike_number = reader["Bike_number"].ToString();
                    dt.start_station = reader["Start_station"].ToString();
                    dt.start_station_num = reader["Start_station_numb"].ToString();
                    data_cont.Add(dt);
                }
            }

        }
        return data_cont;
    }
```

My procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetData_byvalue(@number nvarchar(50))
AS
BEGIN
 SELECT * FROM data WHERE Start_station_num = @number
END
```

But i can only get one last `Start_station_num` at a time e.g `"31273"`(I have all three `Start_station_num` in my table) maybe because my Loop or my string is wrong ?

Here is what i got from WCF:
[unexpected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GtZz.png)

Comment: You need to create a new instance of Data in each loop iteration. Right now you are just adding the same one.

Comment: @Crowcoder you are right, i'm so stupid that make the same mistake twice

Answer (score 0):

use below function to get rows from the comma separated ids you have

```
Create FUNCTION dbo.CSVToNvarcharTable (@InStr NVARCHAR(MAX))
    RETURNS @TempTab TABLE (id NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL)
    AS
    BEGIN
        ; -- Ensure input ends with comma
        SET @InStr = REPLACE(@InStr + ',', ',,', ',');
        DECLARE @SP INT;
        DECLARE @VALUE NVARCHAR(MAX);
        WHILE PATINDEX('%,%', @InStr) <> 0
        BEGIN
            SELECT @SP = PATINDEX('%,%', @InStr);
            SELECT @VALUE = LEFT(@InStr, @SP - 1);
            SELECT @InStr = STUFF(@InStr, 1, @SP, '');
            INSERT INTO @TempTab
            (
                id
            )
            VALUES  (LTRIM(RTRIM(@VALUE))); -- Ensure input don't have trailing 0's
        END;
        RETURN;
    END;

    GO
```

then pass the string of containing the comma separated ids to DB

like this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetData_byvalue(@number nvarchar(50))
AS
BEGIN

 SELECT * FROM data INNER JOIN dbo.CSVToNvarcharTable(@number) AS funcResult
ON Start_station_num =funcResult.id
END
```

this method save your extra db calls and connection you create each time in loop cost effective.